# close all open connections - MySQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

At certain point of execution of my program their are more than 2 connections ware created, by using

```
Con.Close()
```

only one connection get closed and the remaining goes to sleep state. How can i close all opened connections including sleeping connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class implements `IDisposable`. So you use `Dispose()` method directly. The efficient way of doing is with the `using` block

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
{
// Do something 
}// Here it will automatically call Dispose()
```

You will still need to open the connection but don't need to close it because as I mentioned the `Dispose()` method will take care of the object at the end of the `using` block.

To ensure that connections are always closed, open the connection inside 
    of a using block, as shown in the following code fragment. Doing so ensures that 
    the connection is automatically closed when the code exits the block.

```
Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
connection.Open()
'Do work here; connection closed on following line.'
End Using
```

Comment: so you mean i need not to use `Con.Open()` for opening a connection and `Con.Close()` for closing a connection if i use `Using`? can you clearly explain it in vb.net